# Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error in android studio

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Below is my xml file. In preview there is two error'Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error' & 'Failed to instaniate more than one class'. How ever am able to run the app.But the app crashes and in Logcat no errors are shown.

This is my preview screen shot[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="506dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_main"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1"
        tools:context=".Activity.MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        tools:context=".Activity.MainActivity">

        <!-- our tablayout to display tabs  -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorBlack"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:background="@color/colorOran"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            />

        <!-- View pager to swipe views -->
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:weightSum="4"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_home"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ta_home_icon"
                android:background="@color/colorOran"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_new"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ta_todaydeals_icon"
                android:background="@color/colorOran"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_fav"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ta_fav_icon"
                android:background="@color/colorOran"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_auth"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ta_franchie_icon"
                android:background="@color/colorOran"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Below is appbar_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.jeyashri.kitchen.jeyashriskitchen.Activity.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorOran"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/app_logo"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/img"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_social"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:src="@drawable/share_icon" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Try with changing android version.

Comment: tried changing the version.. Not helping

Comment: For a solution without changing the appcompat library, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44223687#45002903

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio rendering problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195807/android-studio-rendering-problems)

Comment: Make sure your Gradle version is up to date.

Comment: I pity you all slaves working with this * of an IDE. Get some life before you are dead.

Answer (score 326, accepted):

The solution to this problem depends on the version of the Android support library you're using:

## Support library `26.0.0-beta2`

This android support library version has a bug causing the mentioned problem

In your Gradle build file use:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
```

with:

```
buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
```

and

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha8'
```

everything should work fine now.

---

## Library version 28 (beta)

These new versions seem to suffer from similar difficulties again.

In your `res/values/styles.xml` modify the `AppTheme` style from

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

*(note the added `Base.`)*

Or alternatively downgrade the library until the problem is fixed:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

Comment: Thank you! that did it. BTW for us Android dev newbiew is worh saying that change should be performed on build.gradle(Module: app) file

Comment: The response and the comment made my life so much easier!

Comment: I just started today. I came across this issue. This answer asks to compile something, of which I have no idea as it does not explain how to do it. But the answer by tanchap solves issue. He/She clearly explained what to do. It was a simple task fora fresher like me. So I think that should be the answer.

Comment: Newb error for me!  When I set up my new project, I forgot to uncheck the "Backwards Compatibility" option (I don't need backwards compatibility).  I re-created the project with this unchecked and all is good!

Comment: Well 28.0.0-beta01 has this problem again. Not sure why android studio still has this problem when its over a year.

Comment: Just curious: how does one go about figuring something like this out? I would never have guessed...

Comment: Thanks, but why this bug still exists in 2018? For an Android newbie, I cannot create a "Hello World" project because of this bug.

Comment: Changing from `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'` to `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'` works just fine.

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> worked me.

Comment: Perfect! In my case, changing back to the alpha1 fixed it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Dears, please answer my question, I have done what mentioned in the answer, and it fixed the problem, BUT THE QUESTION IS: How on earth should I know that this is the problem ? How should I know (without searching SO) that if I upgraded the version then this may/or will happen ?

Answer (score 277):

found it on this site, it works on me. 
 Modify /res/values/styles.xml from:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style>
```

to:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style>
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation of why this works? It will help people who revisit this in the future.

Comment: March 1st, 2018 confirmed this fixed my issue.

Comment: Just note that, if it doesn't work after adding "Base" in your AppTheme, just goto Theme Option from top of your layout preview,Click on Menifest Themes From Left side options and then select your AppTheme. It will automatically refresh the layout.

Comment: This also worked for me. Does anyone know why this is necessary, though? I've been away from Android for a few years and I cannot believe how much finagling I've had to do to get a simple project up and running. (This includes trying to build/run some of the sample projects provided by Android Studio.)

Comment: July 8th, 2018. This solved my issue. This should be the correct answer.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks. Though I have changed `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3` to `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1` before. in `Module:app`

Comment: July, 16th, 2018, works for me too with 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'.

Comment: 26th of July 2018, works for me too with 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3

Comment: 28 july 2018, only added Base.

Comment: Worked for me, too, without needing to change `implementation [...]-alpha[whatever]`

Comment: This worked for me. 

'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'

Comment: Works as of 31/08/18 :)

Answer (score 26):

June 2018 Issue fixed by using a different appcompact version.
Use these codes onto your project dependencies...

In build.gradle(Module: app) add this dependency

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

Happy Coding... :)

Comment: It's again broken in beta :(

Answer (score 17):

## Method 1:

Locate `/res/values/styles.xml`

Change

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

To

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

## Method 2:

Modify template file(locate: `android-studio/plugins/android/lib/templates/gradle-projects/NewAndroidModule/root/res/values/styles.xml.ftl`)

Change

```
backwardsCompatibility!true>Theme.AppCompat<#else><#if
```

To

```
backwardsCompatibility!true>Base.Theme.AppCompat<#else><#if
```

## Watch Solution On YouTube

[image: Solution]

Answer (score 17):

I also had  this  problem and  it's  solved  as 
change  line  from **res/values/styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to

1. `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`
2. `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

both  solutions  worked

Comment: happy coding :)

Answer (score 7):

Faced the same problem in **Android Studio 3.1.3**

Just go to ***style.xml*** file

and replace Theme name

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

with

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Then **clean** and **rebuild** the project.This will solve the error.

Answer (score 6):

Open preview mode

follow the below link to fix the issue

Fix - Rendering Problems The Following classes could not be found : android.support.v7.internal

goto appTheme ---->  select Holo Theme ---> refresh

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4MxBnwpcUjA

Comment: just changing theme from preview pane to some theme other than AppTheme worked

Comment: It worked for me, just changing the theme other than AppTheme

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

Just change:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta2'
```

to:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
```

[Reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zlG9nh8J5ew)

Answer (score 5):

**Replace** `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01'` with

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

in build.gradle (Module:app).  It fixed my red mark in Android Studio 3.1.3

Comment: Great happy coding

Comment: Is there a way to change this at the app level?  So that this need not be replicated for every project that I have.

Answer (score 4):

in android 3.0.0 canary 6 you must change all 2.6.0 beta2 to beta1 (appcompat,design,supportvector)

Answer (score 3):

This is Worked for me i have made the following changes in Style.xml

Change the Following Code:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

With

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this one:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-beta1'
```

instead of

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-beta2'
```

In my case it removed the rendering problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is the minimum configuration that solves the problem.

use:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    ...
}
```

with:

```
 compileSdkVersion 26
 buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
```

and into the build.gradle file located inside the root of the proyect:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    ....
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem. Nothing like changing theme from Layout preview window helped me.

What helped me was adding this to `Apptheme` in `styles.xml`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
}
```

Still it was giving me the error: "cannot resolve symbol widget...coordinatorLayout". Then I updated my `build.gradle(app)` with:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
}
```

One more thing:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
targetSdkVersion 27
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem with    `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'`.

The solution for me was to go `File` -> `Invalidate Caches / Restart` -> `Invalidate` -> `Close Project` -> Remove project from project window -> `Open Project` (from project window).