# Android studio - Preview not display

Tags: android-studio, preview

I have a project Hello World! But preview not display the TextView "Hello World!"

When i drag and drop other things like button, EditText, the preview also not display

Can someone please tell me how to fix this? Thanks all!

[Screenshot design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygF1y.png)

[Screenshot text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feROA.png)

Comment: Have you tried closing the preview tab and then opening it again? Set text color to black or any colour that isn't #ffffff or try restarting your android studio.. Your code is fine.

Comment: See this answer, might solve the "not showing" "Hello World" TextView: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47611939/1437920