# Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

[image: Error Snap]

build.gradle file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "io.dume.dume"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
 core:3.0.2'
 }
```

**I just created a new projects and found this error dramatically on activity_main.xml i did not changed anything . Is there any Fix?**

Comment: May be duplicate of this :https://stackoverflow.com/a/44858887/9050003

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem. Seems it is a Android Studio bug.

In your styles xml-file change this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Works for me.

Comment: downgrading compact version 28alpha to 27 worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Set your target sdk version to 27 .
Set your compile sdk version to 27  .
And app compat version from 28.0.0-alpha3 to 27.1.1 .

If you still want to use sdk version 28

Just replace alpha3 to alpha1 without changing anything else

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me when that happened, I dont know why it doesn't work with 28:

```
//use this instead 
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
targetSdkVersion 27

dependencies{

//switch to these
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0-alpha'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.0'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix this error using 3 methods on YouTube

[image: Solution]

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me.

Open, res --> values --> styles.xml, here you will find a line like this:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

change it to:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

In otherwords, change DarkActionBar to NoActionBar