# Trying to follow a tutorial - how can I get my UI to be like theirs?

Tags: android

I'm following this tutorial right now: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui

I've done all the steps it lists, 
[yet my screen looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37UcZ.png)

On their tutorial [it looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcHOE.png)

I can't figure out how to get the "Hello World!" to show up. I've followed their tutorial word for word, even restarted the whole thing to see if I messed anything up. Am I missing a simple tickbox or something?

Comment: Please note the tiny exclamation mark in a red circle and click it - there should be some information on what is wrong, what does it say?

Comment: [Here are the current errors, definitely stuff about rendering so I guess it's the problem](https://i.imgur.com/srkLGtz.png). I'll try to look them up, hopefully someone here also knows the answer since it does say unknown error.

Edit: I found the answer to my problem! I used [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47573864/8943382). From the answer: Go to appTheme -> select Holo Theme -> Refresh

Thanks for telling me where to look for the error!!

Comment: @0X0nosugar, I edited last comment with the fix I found. Thanks so much for telling me where to find the errors!