# Android Studio: Textview is not shown in certain themes like (AppTheme,AppCompat) but visible/Shown in other themes

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, sdk, android-emulator

I am facing issues like Textview is not shown in certain themes like (AppTheme,AppCompat) but visible/Shown in other themes like(DeviceDefualt,Holo,Material).

**What should I do to get Textview in AppTheme,AppCompat?**

```
***Please see the attached screenshots.***
[AppTheme][1] [DeviceDefault][2] [Light][3][AppCompat][4]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7gof.png

  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8f0OW.png

  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEDTe.png

  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bB2j.png
```

Comment: check this answer , i think you have the same issue
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44858887/2391222

Answer (score 0):

My issue got resolved.
I have posted a video on youtube on how I solved it.
You can check it here:
https://youtu.be/PBE6sBMYDH0