# Hello world and guidelines not showing up in blueprint in Android studio

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio-3.0, blueprint

I am trying to follow this tutorial (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui) to build a basic app. I am pretty sure that I have followed all the directions correctly, but after getting to figure 3 of Build a simple user interface, my blueprint is just a  solid blue rectangle and does not look like figure 3 in the tutorial.

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Show us your code and layout markup.

Comment: I added the code but im not familiar with the term layout markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm cruising around looking for better answers to this problem I'm slinging this S.O. solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47611939/1437920 that worked for me.

Unfortunate the "Hello World" example that is pre-built didn't go well for you, that can be discouraging.

Comment: I appreciate your help and I’ll be sure to let you know if this solves my problem.