# Android Studio: Can't add Views on GridLayout. android/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview, grid-layout

I've been struggling with this for a good couple of hours. Why does this happen? I'm following a course from a website(not sure if i can mention) and everything should work flawlessly, except it doesn't for me.
Essentially, what I'm trying to do is do a "Connect Four" game, and I want to use a GridLayout and add ImageViews in it. When I try to add the ImageViews to the gridLayout, they're not showing. They "exist", but not really showing.
What I tried so far:

- changing layout's height and width
- playing around with the background, visibility
- googling the hell out of this problem.
- add vertical orientation to the gridlayout
- creating everything from scratch again
- "Invalidate Caches/Restart..."

  ```
  Stack Trace

  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener
  at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.load(ModuleClassLoader.java:180)
  at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:61)
  at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:118)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213)
  at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.isLayoutRtlCompat(GridLayout.java:679)
  at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.onLayout_Original(GridLayout.java:1082)
  at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.onLayout(GridLayout.java)
  at android.view.View.layout_Original(View.java:19659)
  at android.view.View_Delegate.layout(View_Delegate.java:91)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19645)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
  at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout_Original(ConstraintLayout.java:1858)
  at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java)
  at android.view.View.layout_Original(View.java:19659)
  at android.view.View_Delegate.layout(View_Delegate.java:91)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19645)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
  at android.view.View.layout_Original(View.java:19659)
  at android.view.View_Delegate.layout(View_Delegate.java:91)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19645)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1083)
  at android.view.View.layout_Original(View.java:19659)
  at android.view.View_Delegate.layout(View_Delegate.java:91)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19645)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
  at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:346)
  at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:384)
  at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
  at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:544)
  at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:678)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  ```

  activity_main.xml

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  ```

  ```
  <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
      android:layout_width="368dp"
      android:layout_height="359dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      android:background="@drawable/board2"
      android:visibility="visible"
      app:columnCount="3"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.6"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
      app:rowCount="3">

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/imageView"
          android:layout_width="50dp"
          android:layout_height="50dp"
          android:background="@drawable/red"
          android:visibility="visible"
          app:srcCompat="@drawable/red" />
  </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
  ```

Comment: Solved partially by doing this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51305964/android-view-viewonunhandledkeyeventlistener-onmeasure-error

Answer (score 1):

I am new to Android I also suffering from same error,
but i found a simple way for Grid Layout is try using basic `<GridLayout>` tag instead of `<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>`
Cheap Way...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue by going into the text view and adjusting some of the xml code.

```
    <GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="3"
    android:background="@drawable/board"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout">
    
    </GridLayout>

    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:onClick="dropIn"
    android:tag="0"/>
```

Essentially I just moved the ImageView code inside of the grid layout code, rather than having it after. Hope this makes sense!

```
    <GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="3"
    android:background="@drawable/board"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout">

    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:onClick="dropIn"
    android:tag="0"/>

    
    </GridLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Reece, Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add codes directly into your answer instead of posting images of it. Also, you can check the [guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) here...