# android/view/view$on unhandled keyevent listener error

Tags: android, layout, toolbar

When i create a new layout in `Android Studio` , I can't put anything on it literally (with root element `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`, by going layout->new->ressourse file)

I can't even change the background color! it shows me

> "android/view/view$on unhandled keyevent listener"

the error is on the photo number 2

[image]
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51305964/android-view-viewonunhandledkeyeventlistener-onmeasure-error

Comment: i know this , and it dosen't work for me..

Comment: You should have mentioned that. Does it compile successfully?

Comment: no , when i sync , it dosen't compile https://scontent.ftun2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/37426830_1117011955104874_7624362283853938688_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=c7b6ab366c0436629608890278bdfb7a&oe=5BC76BB9

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything underlined. Try the following

---

1. Install the missing plattforms like `Android Studio` suggests in your screenshot from the comments
2. Be sure to add `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'` to your `build.gradle`
3. If that doesn't work maybe it's just a rendering problem for the design preview. Therefore you can switch to another `Theme` right above the UI which says `AppTheme`.

Let me know if this helps

Comment: same issue :'( iam about to cry xD

Comment: by the way i changedt theme and the button red at the top changed to blue ,but i want it as app theme to continue..

Answer (score 0):

```
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

add these two library hope this will work

Comment: i changed but they are underlined with red and i can create a layout (fixed)  , i did not change the CompileSdKversion and the CompileSdkVersion  to 27 ,  and now i find a another problem who i sturggeled with : https://scontent.ftun4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/37639552_1119742624831807_6512686660155604992_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=5a96c97b3aa43196c721d413ef51a8c8&oe=5BE43718  "the platform cannot support ssr "

Comment: can you send code of "android/view/view$on unhandled keyevent listener" this error

Comment: this error no more happened when i changed to 27.1.1 but they were underlined with red ! like this photo i send already in the comment , and the other error if you know it before (pllatform cannot support ssr )