# The platform cannot support SSR

Tags: android, platform, server-side-rendering

*Hello everyone !*

how to deal with this two things ?

I unistalled the android studio before (completely) and then installed it again, the first error I don't know it literally , but the second already happened to me before and I fixed it with invalidate caches and restart , but right know this doesn't work for me , and I didn't find anyone who had this problem before.

[image: error image]

Comment: is the parent theme you're using the wrong one?

Comment: i changed the theme in colors.xml , for my project , got another error also and i posted it but dosen't work for me , here the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51433013/android-view-viewon-unhandled-keyevent-listener-error