# OnUnhandledKeyEventListener class not found

Tags: android, android-support-library, classnotfoundexception, android-support-design, android-9.0-pie

I am having error on every support design widget. Like the recyclerview, coordinator layout etc. Everytime, I add a support design widget it is showing

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener
```

on layout issue section. I'm using api 28.0.0-rc01, gradle 4.4 android 3.1.4. Here, is my build.gradle (app) file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.test5test"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
}
```

Here is my layout file

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/work_tab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="5dp"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the stack trace of the error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.load(ModuleClassLoader.java:180)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:61)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:118)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213)
    at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$SlidingTabIndicator.setSelectedIndicatorHeight(TabLayout.java:2402)
    at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.<init>(TabLayout.java:425)
    at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.<init>(TabLayout.java:399)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:481)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:264)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:222)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:209)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:337)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:348)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:248)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:866)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:325)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:384)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:544)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:678)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have checked the View class file, but the "OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" was in there. Don't know why this problem is occurring. Please, tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: How did you solved that? Please add an answer. I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I have solved this problem by updating my api from "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01" to "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2"

Comment: Well, I only realized that this "error" is just a warning this after asking here. This message doesn't do anything to the app itself, but I just got stuck looking for this while another error (on code) was happening. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android/view/view$onUnhandledKeyEventListener (onMeasure error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51305964/android-view-viewonunhandledkeyeventlistener-onmeasure-error)

Answer (score 7):

Open **styles.xml** in app > src > main > res > values folder and change this line

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Comment: You need to Clean the project and remove the `build` folder then it works

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no workaround unfortunately. android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat does not implement View.OnUnhandledKeyEventListener in the androidx package.
The bug has been submitted [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120750246).

Answer (score 0):

if someone has the same error, please, remove the next line of code  from

> res>values>stiles

```
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />-
```

as @Kishan Viramgama or patrick hugh said...

Answer (score -3):

Steps

1. add this to gradle 
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
2. implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1' same version as above.
3. style.xml

   ```
     <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
                               to
     <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
   ```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Can you please [edit] your answer and format  it to make it readable? It also looks truncated. Can you finish it?