# android/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEvent Listener error

Tags: android, android-studio

So I added the GridLayout. Set the rowCount and columnCount to 3 and then tried adding an ImageView. Upon adding the imageview I get the error.

Error:  android/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEvent Listener

NOTE: I have changed the styles.xml to Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar already

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51340607)
there seems to be a bug changing the sdk version would solve it. I suggest you search for an answer on stack more rigorously before actually asking a question to avoid duplicate questions