# Error Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, android, xml

Im trying to make a simple memory game, by now I only done the XML code.
but for some reson i cant understand, at the logcat i get an error 
`Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` 
at this java line:`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`.

this line was wrote by the app when i created it automatically.

here is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/hearthstonefont"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="@string/hint"
        android:fontFamily="@font/hearthstonefont" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGame"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/pCounter"
        android:fontFamily="@font/hearthstonefont" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPoints"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/gCounter"
        android:fontFamily="@font/hearthstonefont" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/title"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/cardback"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibum"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:contentDescription="@string/title"
            android:src="@drawable/cardback" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibur"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/title"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:src="@drawable/cardback" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibdl"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/title"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:src="@drawable/cardback"  />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibdm"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/title"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/cardback"  />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibdr"
            android:contentDescription="@string/title"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:src="@drawable/cardback"  />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="bottom" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNewGame"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:background="@drawable/btngood"
            android:fontFamily="@font/hearthstonefont"
            android:text="@string/btnNewGame"
            android:textSize="17sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btNewPlayer"
            android:background="@drawable/btngood"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="@font/hearthstonefont"
            android:text="@string/btnNewPlayer"
            android:textSize="17sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

here is my java code:

```
package com.example.maor_memorygame;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

logcat:

```
2020-01-19 15:20:05.672 1139-1139/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.673 1139-1139/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2020-01-19 15:20:05.791 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.maor_memorygame-2/lib/x86
2020-01-19 15:20:05.849 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
2020-01-19 15:20:05.876 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
2020-01-19 15:20:05.877 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2341)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.877 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:62)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.877 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.877 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.877 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:645)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.877 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:787)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.877 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:727)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.877 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:858)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.877 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:821)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.877 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:518)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.877 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:426)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.877 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:377)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.877 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:607)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.877 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.877 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.877 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.877 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void com.example.maor_memorygame.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:12)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.877 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6679)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.877 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1118)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.877 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2618)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.877 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2726)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.877 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.877 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1477)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.877 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.877 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.877 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6119)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.877 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.877 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:886)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.877 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:776)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.877 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.maor_memorygame-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.maor_memorygame-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
2020-01-19 15:20:05.877 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.878 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.878 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.878 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2341)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.878 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:62)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.878 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.878 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.878 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:645)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.878 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:787)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.878 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:727)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.878 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:858)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.878 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:821)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.878 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:518)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.878 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:426)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.878 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:377)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.878 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:607)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.878 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.878 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.878 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.878 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void com.example.maor_memorygame.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:12)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.878 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6679)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.878 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1118)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.878 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2618)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.878 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2726)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.879 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.879 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1477)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.879 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.880 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.880 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6119)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.880 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.880 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:886)
2020-01-19 15:20:05.880 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:776)
2020-01-19 15:20:06.348 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2020-01-19 15:20:06.348 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2020-01-19 15:20:06.368 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 9304(551KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 37% free, 6MB/10MB, paused 1.534ms total 18.933ms
2020-01-19 15:20:06.368 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2020-01-19 15:20:06.379 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art: Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 37% free, 6MB/10MB, paused 1.315ms total 10.152ms
2020-01-19 15:20:06.379 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2020-01-19 15:20:06.398 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 126(5KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 37% free, 6MB/10MB, paused 1.371ms total 18.414ms
2020-01-19 15:20:06.398 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 387MB allocation
2020-01-19 15:20:06.398 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2020-01-19 15:20:06.415 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(72B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 37% free, 6MB/10MB, paused 1.547ms total 16.002ms
2020-01-19 15:20:06.415 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 406425612 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 377MB until OOM"
2020-01-19 15:20:06.415 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2020-01-19 15:20:06.415 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2020-01-19 15:20:06.425 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art: Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 4(752B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 37% free, 6MB/10MB, paused 975us total 9.026ms
2020-01-19 15:20:06.425 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2020-01-19 15:20:06.440 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6(144B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 37% free, 6MB/10MB, paused 1.719ms total 14.523ms
2020-01-19 15:20:06.440 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2020-01-19 15:20:06.458 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(72B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 37% free, 6MB/10MB, paused 1.054ms total 17.991ms
2020-01-19 15:20:06.458 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 387MB allocation
2020-01-19 15:20:06.458 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2020-01-19 15:20:06.476 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(72B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 37% free, 6MB/10MB, paused 2.155ms total 17.667ms
2020-01-19 15:20:06.476 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 406425612 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 377MB until OOM"
2020-01-19 15:20:06.477 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame D/skia: --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
2020-01-19 15:20:06.480 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-01-19 15:20:06.482 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.maor_memorygame, PID: 1139
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.maor_memorygame/com.example.maor_memorygame.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.maor_memorygame.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 406425612 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 377MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:620)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:455)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1155)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:720)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:858)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:928)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4202)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:579)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:211)
2020-01-19 15:20:06.482 1139-1139/com.example.maor_memorygame E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:207)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:203)
            ... 25 more
```

app gradle.build:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.maor_memorygame"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Can you share full stack trace?

Comment: added to the post

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`. Keep reading.

Answer (score 1):

Your actual exception is ClassNotFoundException.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener"
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51957944/android-view-viewonunhandledkeyeventlistener) out, perhaps it helps.

Comment: i didnt understand what to do, can you please explain what exactly what to do?

Comment: Would be helpful if you can post your app level build.gradle file as well.

Comment: added to the post