# How to fix "Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error." for api 28?

Tags: android, android-appcompat

This question is a duplicate of
[Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44449275/failed-to-load-appcompat-actionbar-with-unknown-error-in-android-studio)

But I am getting the same error again for API 28. My build.gradle looks like this:

```
    apply plugin: com.android.application
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.application"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug{
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
            ext.alwaysUpdateBuildId = false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation files('libs/graphview-4.2.2-javadoc.jar')
}
```

What is the fix for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USE  implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0-alpha1' instead  implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0-alpha3'.

Comment: This answer seems to be effective as on 30/07/18 - all libraries above 28.0.0-alpha1 result in the error described by the OP - this includes 28.0.0-alpha3 and 28.0.0-beta01.

Comment: It also works for me. Version `28.0.0-beta01` still has the same problem.

Comment: rc01 and rc02 has still the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

In your Gradle file use :

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
buildToolsVersion '26.0.0' 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha8
```

Comment: It produces the error "This support library should not use a different version (26) than the compileSdkVersion (28)". Though the project gets compiled it still does not show the action bar.

Comment: Can you please explain how your solution works and why it does?