# Android studio component not showing in layout editor

Tags: java, android-studio, textview

I was trying to add new buttons and text views to the layout of android studio.

However, in the preview of the layout the text views and buttons are not showing up in layout editor.

I have also changed the theme type but still it is not working.

[image: this is the image i have taken a text view and a plain button but it is not showing up in the layout editor]

Answer (score 0):

you just have to drag and drop button and textviews on the layout editor. 
nothing else.

Rebuild and Clean Project to get Changes on the Layout Editor as well. It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Change the 'Theme' to 'Classic' and the Build->Clean project.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the same problem of:
[Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44449275/failed-to-load-appcompat-actionbar-with-unknown-error-in-android-studio/51261291)

If using library version 28 beta, in `res/values/styles.xml` file, change this line:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```