# AppCompat ActionBar failed to load with unknown error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat

Failed to load `AppCompatActionBar` with unknown error.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
}
```

Build.gradle(Module:app)

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Refer: [Here. This might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44449275/failed-to-load-appcompat-actionbar-with-unknown-error-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
```

with:

```
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
```

and

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
```

Comment: It shows : Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0