# Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar vs Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-theme

when I update to android 3.1.3 the design screen not showing anything I googled it and found the solution to change the appTheme parent to

> Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

instead of

> Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

**and worked perfectly.**

my question is

why doesn't it work with default one and what is the difference between two themes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be any difference. If you look up style definition in values.xml of your `appcompat` library, you can see that `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` just extends `Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` and nothing else.

The problem seems that there was a bug with how Android Studio handled some versions of the support library. You can find a more detailed answer here:

[Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44449275/failed-to-load-appcompat-actionbar-with-unknown-error-in-android-studio)

Anyway, after updating Android Studio to 3.2 and Gradle to 4.6, the problem is gone.