# Error - Failed to load AppCombat Actionbar with unknown error

Tags: android, xml, gradle

I just created a new Android project and just tried adding some text fields to my activity main and I am already getting errors. None of the other suggested solutions have helped.
Here is the error and my current gradle.

Error screenshot:
[image: Error screenshot]

current gradle:
[image: current gradle]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44449275/failed-to-load-appcompat-actionbar-with-unknown-error-in-android-studio

Comment: Be careful when posting external links, many people will not follow them blindly. Consider adding the error message directly.

Answer (score -1):

There are some bugs at latest update of support libraries so solution downgrade the library until the problem is fixed, dependencies code should be like below

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha1'
```