# Android Studio components aren't displaying and app does not run

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android Studio and want to know why it does not really work for me.

Basically, I just started learning Android Studio watching an online course, so I am just doing the same thing what the lecturer does on the videos, but the result never turns out the same.

Firstly I want to let you know that I have not touched anything. But Android Studio does not show any of components, such as textView, and when I run it, the ADB(the Emulator) never runs the app but only shows the default screen of an Android phone.

I better attach some screenshots of my Android Studio to show you what is going on.

[image]

As you can see from this picture, there is a textView component but it does not appear on the screen that is in the center.

As I wrote above, I did not touch anything. It is just right after I create a new project. No matter what component I add, it never shows up.

I have no idea if it would matter but if you look at the top right, an error occurs (red exclamation mark) that is saying "Render Problem: Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error".

I have tried to solve this error for several hours and could not really find a solution to this too.

And when I run the app (by pressing green arrow button), here's what happens.

[image]

It just stays on this screen. Nothing really happens after this.

What should I do to see my components and to make it run the app? What am I missing? I really have done exactly the same as the online course I am watching and I see no one is having the problem I am facing now.

Any help?

In case of it will be needed, I am uploading both of my gradle files too:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is a gradle file build.gradle (Project: project name)

And the following is a gradle file build.gradle (Module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.auclo.exampleapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

And styles.xml

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your gradle files (both of them)?

Comment: @JacobCelestine I just edited the post and uploaded both of them, can you check?

Comment: you have to see build tab (side of logcat) error

Comment: try to create new Linear layout and add some buttons on it. If it doesn't work try to change the device screen.

Comment: @Auclown Gradle looks good. Can you post your styles.xml? The path would be res/values/styles.xml

Comment: post code of your xml file. 
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3' add this below compileSdkVersion in build.gradle (Module: app)

Comment: This is a problem related to version 28.may be the version is still unstable.Please downgrade to version 27 in your app.gradle file

Comment: if you just want to see the the preview of your xml file while using the latest version (28.0.0-rc01) just change the AppTheme to something else like Material Light-> Dark Action Bar

Comment: Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue of version 28, you should downgrade to version 27 until the problem is solved.

Go to your app/Gradle Scripts/build.gradle (Module:app)

[image: where is build.gradle located]

**1**

Change this line:

```
compileSdkVersion 28
```

to

```
compileSdkVersion 27
```

**2**

Change this line:

```
targetSdkVersion 28
```

to

```
targetSdkVersion 27
```

**3**

Change this line:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

Then Android Studio will ask you to Sync the files, and you do so by clicking in **Sync Now**

Keep learning how to code, and soon Android will solve this problem. You can see more about this discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44449275/failed-to-load-appcompat-actionbar-with-unknown-error-in-android-studio).

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to wait till i'm clear but since everyone is telling him to downgrade the project, here I go.

There's a bug in the newer versions. So if you want to run your project on sdk 28, in your *res/values/styles.xml* modify the AppTheme style from

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Basically waht you have to do is add *Base* to whatever is already there.

Or

As the others said you can downgrade your project to:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

But I think you should always learn on the latest so you're free to choose either options :)

Comment: Anytime. feel free to comment links of any other questions you've and i'll check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Go to styles.xml and change

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

to

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

Answer (score 2):

Change Depandency

> This is an issue of version 28, you should downgrade to version 27 until the problem is solved.

`compileSdkVersion 28` to `compileSdkVersion 27`

`targetSdkVersion` 28 to `targetSdkVersion 27`

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
```

replace with

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!