# Can't find device screen option in my component tree window

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I am following a udemy tutorial series in which the instructor is using a different version of Andriod-Studio and I am currently using the latest version and there is a difference in layout. The instructor is doing stuff using the device component where as i am unable to do all that.

I am a beginner so I have no idea how to manage or where to find it

The instructor is editing in the text field in his device's screen whereas I don't even see a text field in my screen

**Here is my screen** :

[image]

**And here is  my instructor screen:**

[image]

Comment: link of pictures are given in the question. kindly look at the left hand side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to drag your textView into the layout editor screen :

[image]

After you have done that open the attributes sidebar:[image]

And now click on the textView, in the attribute bar that you opened type "text" and change the text of your view :

[image]

**Edit according to the comments:**

Press the text tab :
[image]

And now just change your layout :

[image]

Comment: This view is not constrained. It only has designtime positions, so it will jump to (0,0) at runtime unless you add the constraints  The layout editor allows you to place widgets anywhere on the canvas, and it records the current position with designtime attributes (such as layout_editor_absoluteX). These attributes are not applied at runtime, so if you push your layout on a device, the widgets may appear in a different location than shown in the editor. To fix this, make sure a widget has both horizontal and vertical constraints by dragging from the edge connections

Comment: i get the error i mentioned above and plus when i drag and drop textview i can't see it on the screen

Comment: You need to give your view proper [constraints](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) so you can see it. In my answer, I only answered how to put your view on your screen. if you want to see it set the proper constraints.

Comment: something like this : `<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />`

Comment: Also, if this answer solved your problem please accept it so others with the same problem could know to use it.

Comment: sorry to bother you tamir but it didnt and brought a bunch of more problems

Comment: I think that this is your first time using constraint layout, go to the XML and change your layout to `RelativeLayout` from `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: - rendering problem -missing constraints in constraintslayout -hardcoded text -failed to instanstiate more than one classes

Comment: and how do i do that?

Comment: Ok my bad, I jumped a bit ahead, in your  instructor  screen he is using `RelativeLayout`, so go to the XML display and change it to `RelativeLayout ` as i showed in previous comment

Comment: and how do I do that?  - On the left bottom corner, you can see the Design and text tab, swap to text. change your layout and return to the design option.

Comment: can you kindly guide me through the steps? i am a complete beginner and unfamiliar with the UI of android studio

Comment: I will add an image of it

Comment: than you so much bro <3

Comment: Check the answer now

Comment: Render Probelm "Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error" still can't see it :'( and also failed to instantiate error

Comment: i dont see a text field on the white screen when i drag and drop like you or my instructor . is there any way my view can look exactly like my instructor's?

Comment: For this problem check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44449275/failed-to-load-appcompat-actionbar-with-unknown-error-in-android-studio)

Comment: Bro tysm <3 it worked! i had to change apptheme to <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> in res/values/styles.xml

Comment: Glad it helped you, kindly accept the answer. happy coding