# How to enable/show Device screen in component Tree of resource layout xml file?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

I want to see the whole view of my phone instead of just the screen in xml resource layout when designing the UI pane, so as to give me a better idea of how the app will look like on the phone.

A similar Question has been posted a month ago [Can't find device screen option in my component tree window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55695097/cant-find-device-screen-option-in-my-component-tree-window]) but the answer wasn't helpful. In addition, I have tried searching online but no relevent threads/forums related to this could be found. Hence seeking the public's advice on this. Thanks in advance from a Beginner! :D

Answer (score 0):

If your android studio version is between 2.2 - 3.1 you can

1- Click on designer preview window

2 - press F button from your keyboard

Taken from [android studio designer preview: how to include device frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43132508/9233991)

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I'm currently using the latest android studio version 3.4. I have tried out as outlined in the above suggested solution, but it does not work. Is there any other means to go about achieving it? Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this comment at the same post https://stackoverflow.com/a/54894173/9233991