# Rendering Problem in Android Studio Layout Preview

Tags: android-studio, layout, android-emulator

I've looked at the suggested answers and none of them get the layout preview to render properly. I have tried changing the theme and lowering the API.

With "AppTheme" selected as the theme, the layout preview does not render elements properly and does not match the emulator. The error messages, .xml, emulator and layout preview are shown in the screenshot.

Please let me know what information is needed. I am new-ish to android studio.

[image]

// Edit

The solution given by Jadhu worked with my previous IDE version. However, I also wanted to see the Action Bar in the preview. I tried to use the solution listed in the Jadhu's link but it still did not show the Action Bar.

After updating the IDE, I no longer need to make any changes but the Action Bar still will not appear.

// Edit 2

Make the Action Bar appear by clicking the "Eye Symbol" drop-down on the upper-left corner of the preview and selecting `Show Layout Decorations`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your res/values/styles.xml and change the:

"style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar""

to

"style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar""

if it doesnt work, you may find the answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44449275/failed-to-load-appcompat-actionbar-with-unknown-error-in-android-studio), please feel free to take a look.

Comment: Thank you, it worked to a degree. I've put an edit.

Comment: Welcome, glad i've helped.